# Using get_queried_object in functions.php to pass data for ajax load more posts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've looked everywhere on here and also a broad Google search but haven't found anything specific to this problem. I am trying to create a typical "load more" button functionality that works on a custom post type taxonomy archive page. Here's what I have so far:

```
// Load more posts
add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');

function load_posts_by_ajax_callback() {
    $the_issue_key = $_POST['the_issue_key'];
    check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');
    $paged = $_POST['page'];
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'case_study',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_archive_page' => '2',
        'paged' => $paged,
        );
    $my_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) :
        ?>
        <?php while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post() ?>
            <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $queried_object; ?></p>
            <?php the_excerpt() ?>
        <?php endwhile ?>
        <?php
    endif;
    wp_die();
}
```

The script:

```
// Script
var ajaxurl = 'http://ovo2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'; 
var page = 2;
jQuery(function($) {

    $('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function() {
        var data = {
            'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
            'page': page,
            'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_posts"); ?>'
        };

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            $('.my-posts').append(response);
            page++;
        });

    });
});
```

This works fine but it loads ALL case_study CPT posts when what I really need is taxonomy specific posts. Within my archive page itself I have added to the $args array for the first two posts that display on page load:

```
    'tax_query' => array (
        array (
            'taxonomy' => $queried_object->taxonomy,
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $queried_object->term_id,
            ),
        ),
```

And it pulls the taxonomy specific posts but when I add it to the function in my functions file to load more posts it doesn't work. It seems pretty obvious that it's something to do with not being able to pass variables from `get_queried_object` from php to script but I'm not sure how to solve this.

I have also tried using `wp_localize_script` but haven't been able to set it up correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As a last-ditch effort to solve my problem and get the functionality I needed I decided to search for a reputable plugin that might do everything I needed, and I actually found one: [AJAX Load More](https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/)

With the Filters add-on I was able to set up in 10 minutes what I'd been trying to do myself for close to 8 hours. Though its functionality is more specific in scope I would put this plugin right up there with ACF Pro in terms of professionalism and support. There are very few plugins I use on a site build but I'll be adding this one to the list.